# Knee-Deep In The Dead Core Data Stack (Two SQL Stores with a Single Model)

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, persistent-storage

I've setup the Core Data Stack in the App Delegate.  I've preloaded it with seed data and have user data that can be saved to the same store.

I have a to-many relationship in the model.

I'm trying to split the two stores, separating the seed data from the user data.  They are however, using the same model.

I've passed both contexts and stores (seed and user) to their respective VC's (mirroring) so seed and user data can be created and displayed.

The parent nodes save and display properly, however once I load the VC to display the children, I consistently get an _NSFaultingMutableSet Error:
[_NSFaultingMutableSet itemName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9e91ff0'
This error occurs in cellforrowatindexpath on VC to display the children.

The stack/model doesn't recognize the entities in the to-many relationship with multiple stores and contexts.  This error does not occur when both seed and user data are in the same store.

I've tried:

- initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType]; for the both contexts.
- Separating the seed and user VC's (they currently use the same VC, which worked with the same    store).

I'll post code but I'm not sure exactly if the problem is in the model?
The core data stack in the app delegate?
The mirroring the of context and stores to the VC's?

Any thoughts on using two separate stores would be appreciated, tutorials or best practices for this use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to follow this tutorial to achieve what I was looking for: http://commandshift.co.uk/blog/2013/06/06/multiple-persistent-stores-in-core-data/

I used the same model and was able to change the code from the tutorial to get it working.

Will work through the "Fetched Properties" to finesse things a bit more.  At this point, results from both files are being thrown into a single array...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you will be able to do it with two stores, unless you are able to get it to work with fetched properties: From the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html):

**Cross-Store Relationships**

You must be careful not to create relationships from instances in one persistent store to instances in another persistent store, as this is not supported by Core Data. If you need to create a relationship between entities in different stores, you typically use fetched properties (see “Fetched Properties”).